# Why is a (self) join so slow with Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, performance, virtual-layer

I use QGIS 3.4 on Windows 10

I have a polygon layer and a point layer. The points have a streetname attribute. I want to check if there are polygons with more then 1 streetname.

I took 2 steps, first Join attributes by location to get the streetnames as attribute in the polygons.
The second step is a self join in a virtual layer

```
SELECT T1.POLid, T1.Postalcode, T1.streetname, T2.streetname
FROM TestStreet AS T1, TestStreet AS T2
WHERE T1.POLid = T2.POLid AND T1.streetname <> T2.streetname;
```

I have to interrupt the processing after waiting very long.

My workaround is:

```
Save features As csv file
Import csv file in MSAccess
MSAccess gives instantaneous results with the same query.
```

What is it what I do wrong in QGIS, is there a better way just with QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is likely with the `join by attribute` being re-evaluated many times.

You can skip this step and compute everything at once in a virtual layer. As a bonus, it will tell you if you have more than 2 streets in a polygon.
Eventually, you can filter the entries having a single street name

```sql
SELECT p.polyID, COUNT(DISTINCT s.streetName) as cnt, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.streetName) as names
FROM myPolygonLayer p
JOIN myStreetLayer s ON ST_INTERSECTS(p.geometry, s.geometry)
GROUP BY p.polyID
--HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.streetName) >= 2
```

Comment: The first step join attribute by location was fast, the virtual layer part was very slow.

I get the following error by copy and pasting your code (I only changed the layer- and filednames: 


Query preparation error on SELECT "COUNT(DISTINCT s.openbare_ruimte)", "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.openbare_ruimte, ';')" FROM _tview LIMIT 1: DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument

Comment: @Jan see edits with the removed separator (not too sure why it complains when Distinct is there)

Comment: I took your edits, now when I hit TEST there is no error message but I stopped the proces after several minutes.